# How to format autogenned columns in ASP.Net GridView?

Tags: gridview, formatting

Until now, I've always explicitly formatted every column in my GridView.

But now, my datasource can vary in number of columns, so I autogenerate="true"

That leaves me with no place to define the format, so all the non-string fields have four decimal places when I want two-decimal accounting format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GridView.RowDatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to access the values in each row. Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/FrmtAutoGenClmnASPNETGrid.aspx) covering it.  Optionally, you can access the [GridView.Databound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event and iterate over the rows yourself.